# Using e.preventDefault(); to prevent clicking a link twice

Tags: jquery, off-canvas-menu

I'm trying to close an off canvas navigation panel by clicking on a link in that panel. You can open/close the panel with a hamburger button and close it when you click anywhere on the page.

See: http://whyyouthinking.com/xindex.html#what

I got to the point where it was working but the hamburger had to be clicked twice to work again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  "use strict";
  $('.panel ul li a').on("click", function () {
     $('.menu-link').removeClass("active");
     $('.panel').animate({left: '-=250'});
  });
});
```

I've got round that with:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('.panel ul li a').on("click", function () {
       $('.menu-link').removeClass("active");
       $('.panel').animate({left: '-=250'});
     });
    $('.panel ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('.menu-link').click();         
    });
  });
```

Now I have the problem that the e.preventDefault(); is also stopping my 'scrollto' function, when you click on a link in the panel. Is there a way of just targeting the .menu-link?

Comment: You're doing it wrong, you need to figure out *why* it has to be clicked twice, and fix it, not just hack it by triggering a click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Scroll to event registered to "#menu" selector as well,  so when ever user clicks on panel list anchor tag, its scrolling to target offset, as well as #menu target offset due to $('.menu-link').click();.

So restrict page scroll animation to #menu selector. A #menu selector conditional check added: `if(target.selector != "#menu" && target.length)`.

```
/*Scroll to function*/
$(function() {
    "use strict";
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.selector != "#menu" && target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - 60
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

It would be nice if you unregister event for #menu selector, check this: `$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]):not([href="#menu"])').click(function(e) {...}`

Comment: Thank you so much, there's not a hope in hell I would have worked that out. The good thing is I'm always learning when more experienced programmers show me how things work.

Comment: I am glad, I was able to help.